# How can I avoid "Windows protected your PC" problem when my friends try to use my executables?

Tags: python, c++, runtime-error

When my friends try to open the executable resulting from building my project (i.e. a ".exe"), they take the error "Windows protected your PC".
Both my c++ and python projects cannot be executed on my friends' computers because of the error.
How can I allow it?

Comment: More importantly, why **doesn't** this block occur on "professional" software? How can we make software that isn't blocked?

Answer (score 5):

This isn't an error; this is a design choice by Microsoft to protect those of us who are not tech-savvy (i.e. potentially your friends). And although it is a little bit annoying, it is not actually a roadblock.

When you click more info,
[image]

you will be met with

[image]

and thus be able to run the program by clicking "Run anyway", despite Microsoft's warning, because you know for a fact that the program is safe - or in this case, your friends know that the program is safe, because you probably don't have any malicious intent.

... Or do you?

Comment: I think OP asked about how to program so that the warning is not  displayed at all (this being a programming community and not a security configuration one....). But that is kind of the exact reason why I like your answer, though it strictly speaking is answering an off-topic question, or an interpretation of a question which is off-topic. Um, you know what I mean. Upvoteable for the idea of StackOverflow, not for the letter of the rules.... :-)

Comment: @Yunnosch I judged, by how the OP phrased his question, and his unawareness of this particular feature, that they are perhaps a beginner, and would benefit more from a quick and easy trick to get them off the ground, than going in and try to explain the world of digital signature verification - which I am not an expert at, and would therefore fail at trying to explain, lol.

Comment: Just in case I was not clear enough: I appreciate the answer and you have my upvote. (This is more for others than for you, because I think you got it...) For slightly different reasons than you describe, but yours are of course also valid .

Comment: @Yunnosch Of course, I was just replying to add context to my own thought process for anyone looking. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 1):

Its due to windows built-in security feature. Try not to send .exe but send your code and your friend could compile it at their own. Windows just not authenticating it, as the source is not verified, according to your friend OS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the windows smart screen to run unpublished apps in Windows 10. Follow the below steps for Windows 8 or 10.
https://www.howtogeek.com/75356/how-to-turn-off-or-disable-the-smartscreen-filter-in-windows-8/

Or you can surf the internet for disabling the windows smartscreen with yours or your friends OS build number.

Comment: I am not a fan of your advice. It also is incomplete. To make it complete, deinstalling firewalls and anti-malware would be needed. Then all annoying warnings about potentially harmful user choices go conveniently away. The other answers have offered solutions which are basically also risky, but at least are restricted to the questionable wisdom of running software created by people you consider friends...